How may I fix the magnetic moment of a system in a QE calculation?
I am currently working on the honeycomb quantum spin liquid candidate Na3Co2SbO6, where the Co atoms form a honeycomb lattice with an octahedral crystal field, which may result in geometric frustration. To analyze the spin exchange interactions in this system, I need to fix the magnetic moment of two Co atoms in a 2x2x1 supercell. Prior studies report the magnetic moment for Co in this system to be around 2.7 μB (as seen in this paper).
While I have previously been able to fix magnetic moments in other systems (e.g., CrI3), I am unable to achieve the expected 2.7 μB for Co in Na3Co2SbO6, no matter how large I set the penalty parameter λ, even increasing it up to 400. In my calculations, the magnetic moment remains below 1 μB, and the constrained energy does not approach zero. Additionally, I have tried to fix the magnetic moment of other Co atoms to 0 or leave them unconstrained, but this does not resolve the issue.
All calculations converge nicely except the constrained energy. I have applied a Hubbard U on the Co atoms and activated spin-orbit coupling, but these steps have not yielded the desired result.
In summary, despite applying appropriate constraints and methods, I cannot fix the magnetic moment of the Co atoms to 2.7 μB in Na3Co2SbO6, and I am seeking insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf'
    prefix='Na3Co2SbO6_neel',
    pseudo_dir = '../../../PSEUDO/',
    outdir='./TMP_DIR/'
 /

&SYSTEM
    ibrav=0
    nat=156
    ntyp=6
    ecutwfc=50
    ecutrho=400
    occupations='smearing'
    smearing='cold'
    degauss=0.02

     ! Here I tune the magnetic moment
     constrained_magnetization = 'atomic'
     lambda = 150.0

     starting_magnetization(1)= 0
     starting_magnetization(5)= 0
     starting_magnetization(6)= 0
     starting_magnetization(2)= 0

     starting_magnetization(3)= 2.7
     angle1(3) = 90
     angle2(3) = 0

     starting_magnetization(4)= 2.7
     angle1(4) = 180
     angle2(4) = 0

     Hubbard_U(2) = 4
     Hubbard_U(3) = 4
     Hubbard_U(4) = 4

     lda_plus_u_kind = 1 ! for spin orbit+U

     noncolin=.true.
     lspinorb=.true.
  /
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr=1.0d-8
    mixing_beta=0.7
    electron_maxstep=200
  /

ATOMIC_SPECIES
    Na  22.989769  na_pbe_v1.5.uspp.F.UPF
    Co  58.933195  Co_pbe_v1.2.uspp.F.UPF
    Co1  58.933195  Co_pbe_v1.2.uspp.F.UPF
    Co2  58.933195  Co_pbe_v1.2.uspp.F.UPF
    Sb  121.76  sb_pbe_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF
    O   15.999  O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF


ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Na    0.000000    1.621685    0.000000
...
O   10.678255   10.746300    3.761881


CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
  5.083873  0.000000  0.000000
  0.000000  9.287230  0.000000
 -1.687042  0.000000  5.610000

K_POINTS automatic
    4 2 2 0 0 0

Here is a picture of the system I am working on.

Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Update: I think QE is generally bad at noncolinear calculations, especially for large system. I moved to VASP and everything worked.
